# Заполнение List списка с помощью SQL запроса C#

Tags: c#, sql-server

Есть MSSQL база в ней 100 записей. Прошу помочь с решением для заполнения list на C#. Все испробовал, не могу найти подходящее решение =(

Comment: Что конкретно не получается?

Answer (score 1):

Непонятно в чем проблема, но я приведу общий алгоритм.

0)Создаете какой-нибудь `List<Tuple<T>>`(а в более красивом решении отдельный класс, который моделирует 1 запись)

1)Создаете `SqlConnection`

2)Открываете его

3)Создаете `SqlCommand`

4)У команды вызываете `ExecuteReader`

5)В цикле while крутитесь до тех пор пока Read=true

6)Вызываете у DataReader'а метод например GetString([индекс колонки]) и добавляете запись в коллекцию.

Готово.

[Тут есть так же пример](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/9kcbe65k(v=vs.110).aspx)